# Postgresql between min max in where

Tags: sql, postgresql

with a Postgresql 9.6 table structure like:

```
who | when
```

Each day has multiple records with same **who** and different **when**. 
Ipotetically each record is a **in** or **out** action for **who**, so need to get total time in for each who.

i.e.

```
who | when
  A | 2017-03-01 08:00 
  A | 2017-03-01 12:00
  A | 2017-03-01 13:00
  A | 2017-03-01 15:00
```

how can I get the total of  **6**hours in?

I think that max(when) - min(when) gets the period but need to subtract the middle data calculating middle min and max.

So need to get the 12:00 as 'morningout' and 13:00 as 'afternoonin' but when I put the betweeen min max in where it complains

> 'no aggregate function possible in where'

```
select who, 
      to_char(date_trunc('day', when), 'YYYY-MM-DD')  "thisday", 
       count(who) as 'signIn'
       min(when) as 'morningout'          
       max(when) as 'afternoonin' 


from the_table 
where when between max(when) and min(when)

group by who, "thisday"
order by who;
```

Comment: Normally you put WHERE between FROM and GROUP BY. For aggregate function conditions you need a HAVING clause instead.

Comment: when is between max(when) and min(when) fro every when of the_table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select   who,
         sum("when" - lag)
from     (select row_number() over w,
                 who,
                 "when",
                 lag("when") over w
          from   t
          window w as (partition by who order by "when")) d
where    row_number % 2 = 0
group by who
```

If you need this *per days*, just use the `date_trunc('day', "when")` in the `group by` clause. You can also put `date_trunc('day', "when")` in the `partition by` clause, inside the window definition to avoid pairing which spans across days:

```
select   who,
         date_trunc('day', "when"),
         sum("when" - lag)
from     (select row_number() over w,
                 who,
                 "when",
                 lag("when") over w
          from   t
          window w as (partition by who, date_trunc('day', "when") order by "when")) d
where    row_number % 2 = 0
group by who, date_trunc('day', "when")
```

However, these solutions require that rows have to be in *in* + *out* pairs. For a more reliable solution, you'll need a `direction` column.

http://rextester.com/UJWWH59178